# How to present a select type(drop down) in a tree view format in Zend_Form

Tags: zend-framework, treeview, zend-form

I am doing a new project in Zend and it needs a drop down which populates y the data from database (i.e Categories).I need to show those categories Data to be shown in the form of Tree view in the Drop Down menu.I have tried a bit doing it by just fetching the data from the database and then arranging them into the ZEND_FORM by using foreach and putting the value into the

```
$category->addMultiOption($childCategory['category_title'] , $childCategory['id']);
```

But still I am not getting the desired value in the Form.Please suggest how to do it because I am very raw in Zend Framework.A small code snippet will be very helpful to understand.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please post the structure of categories table?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by Tree View, but if you want to create optgroups around certain options, you can use the following multiOptions structure:

```
$options = array(
    'option group name' => array(
        'value1' => 'label1',
        'value2' => 'label2',
    ),
    'second group name' => array(
        'value3' => 'label3',
        'value4' => 'label4',
    ),
);
$category->setMultiOptions($options);
```